# Await works fine on async function, but not on promises

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was playing with async/await and have found some strange discrepancy in the behavior, depending where await is called.

```
function test(msg) {
  return new Promise(accept => {
    console.log('in promise ', msg);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('in timeout ', msg);
      accept();
    }, 1000)
  });
}

async function run() {
  await test('a');
  await test('b');
}

run();
```

It outputs

```
in promise  a 
in timeout  a 
in promise  B 
in timeout  B
```

, which is expected. However, if I move await inside "test" function, then the result is changed in a very unexpected manner:

```
async function test(msg) {
  const promise = new Promise(accept => {
    console.log('in promise ', msg);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('in timeout ', msg);
      accept();
    }, 1000)
  });
  await promise;
}

function run() {
  test('a');
  test('B');
}

run();
```

Outputs

```
in promise  a
in promise  B
in timeout  a
in timeout  B
```

Could somebody please explain the behavior in the second case? Thank you.

Comment: Keep in ind that `await` doesn't block execution. It's just allows you to write code dealing with promises differently. `await promise;` in your example is actually completely useless. If you remove it or do `promise.then(() => {})` instead (which is basically what `await` does) then you get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct a Promise, the body of that Promise executes immediately. That's why in the second piece of code, the `console.log`s inside of `new Promise` *before* the `setTimeout` occur right away.

So why in the first example does it not do the same thing? It's because the second call to `test` isn't called until the first completes. The two Promises are essentially chained together, as though you wrote this:

```
return test('a').then(() => test('B'));
```

If you had done this:

```
const promiseA = test('a');
const promiseB = test('B');
await Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB]);
```

...you'd get the same result as the second block of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing I cannot understand is why in the 2nd case the 2nd promise is constructed before first "await" elapses? Await should pause the execution of "test('a')", therefore "test('B')" shouldn't be called at all... or not?

Comment: `await` doesn't "pause" execution. It's just syntax for chaining things together. An async function becomes a function that returns a `Promise`. Unless you await _that_ Promise by the caller, it won't appear to "pause."

Comment: (i.e., you still have to `await` the result of `test(...)`; async/await doesn't make the asynchronous disappear, it just makes it more tolerable to deal with.)

Answer (score 1):

All the `await`ed Promises within an `async` function are executed (to completion) *sequentially*.

In your first scenario, `run` is the `async` function, and its 2 `await` calls to `test` are executed sequentially.

In your second scenario, `test` is the `async` function, and its single `await` operation has no effect whatsoever (since the `async` function has no second `await` operation that needs to "wait").

Answer (score 0):

These two code blocks are identical:

with await

```
await test('a');
test('B');
```

with chaining

```
test('a')
  .then(() => {
    test('B');
  });
```

All you're doing with the `await` is *awaiting* for the promise to resolve to move on. `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar to avoid all the nesting with multiple promises

Comment: I think this is too vague. *"test('B'); doesn't wait for test('a'); to complete before it starts"* But you are also saying that `await` "pauses" execution.

Comment: @FelixKling In the second example, `B` doesn't wait for `a` to complete because `await` is not used

Comment: I understand that. I'm just saying that *"you're basically "pausing" execution of your function until that promise resolves."* can be misinterpreted to "pause" all execution.

Comment: @FelixKling I can see where it could have been confusing. Updated it to be a bit more illustrative of my point

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `run` function is not async, so it just runs the two functions. `async`/`await` is just an alternate syntax for promises, so your second example is equivalent to this:

```
function test(msg) {
  const promise = new Promise(accept => {
    console.log('in promise ', msg);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('in timeout ', msg);
      accept();
    }, 1000)
  });
  return promise.then(() => undefined);
}

function run() {     
  test('a');
  test('B');
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

To see clearly what happens you need to put another `console.log('end')` at the end of your code (after `run();`):

### For the first example the output is:

```
in promise  a
end
in timeout  a
in promise  b
in timeout  b
```

### For the Second example the output is:

```
in promise  a
in promise  B
end
in timeout  a
in timeout  B
```

`await` pauses the execution of the current function until the promise is resolved.

In the **first example** `test('a')` is executed but then `run()` is paused until the promise returned by `test('a')` resolves, causing `console.log('end')` to be executed.

In the **second example** `test('a')` is partially executed, but is paused until the promise is resolved, so `test('b')` is executed next, which is also paused, but then `run()` is finished so `console.log('end')` can be executed.

Hope this explanation helps!

Comment: In the fist example, `end` should be last line in the log, no? *edit:* Ah, `console.log('end')` is literally the last line, not inside `run` I guess.

Comment: You're right, I didn't want to copy/paste the code, it would make my answer very long